# Scala updating Map error

Tags: scala, dictionary, concatenation

I'm trying to write method `addWordToMap`, that shouls add a word `w` to a list in map's values if key occurences equals to `occ`. And I don't understand why compiler says that `map.updated(occ, map.apply(occ)++w)` return `Map[Occurences, List[Any]]`. My idea is there is some troubles with concatenation, but it seems quite correct for me. Thank you!

```
type Word = String
type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]
def addWordToMap(map: Map[Occurrences, List[Word]], 
  w: Word, occ: Occurrences): Map[Occurrences, List[Word]] = {
  map.updated(occ, map.apply(occ)++w)
}
```

Comment: Try if this works,  map.updated(occ, map(occ) :+ w)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `:+`, not `++`.

It compiles with `++` for a combination of unpleasant reasons: it looks like you're trying to concatenate two collections, so the compiler implicitly converts the string to a collection of characters, and you end up with a collection whose element type is the least upper bound of `Char` and `String`, which is `Any`.